# Code for less than or equal to 10 in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the following code to validate my field.
If the number is greater than 10 the validation message is displaying.

```
less_than[10]
```

Now If anyone enter 10,then also the validation message is displaying.
I need a code for less than or equal to 10 in codeIgniter.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Can you provide what you have done up to now (code)?

Comment: @Micha..I have used less than 10..I need to update that to less than or equal to 10..is there any short code in codeIgniter for less than or equl to?..

Comment: @bhai he is asking you to use the [**Edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17417729/edit) to update your question with the your php code. Also you should use the search before posting a new question [**Codeigniter : Validating two fields**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367265/codeigniter-validating-two-fields) See the checked answer it shows how to add a call back to the rule to check for what u need.

Comment: @Prix..I am expecting a short code for less than or equal to like **less_than[10]**

Comment: There is not build in validation rule for "less than or equal". You can write your own validation rule with it's own message. Look at CI documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `less_than[11]`
It would work like less than or equal to 10 ..

Comment: Note about the message is less than not less than or equal. To custom the message must define another rule!

Comment: @secretlm that's exactly why he is making it 11 and not 10 read carefully.

Comment: @Prix: yeah, I see but I mean the message when validation is failed, it will be less than 11 characters instead of less than or equal to 10 characters.

Comment: @secretlm regardless it means the same thing using different words ;)

Comment: this is valid solution in my opinion, this solution popped as 1st in my mind... pure logic. OP can set own `display error message`

Answer (score 2):

Create your own custom callback function within the controller that maintains your form validations rules and which calls the `form_validation` class:

```
public function index()
{
    //...form stuff 

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('number', 'Number', 'callback_less_than_or_equal[10]');

    //...form stuff
}

public function less_than_or_equal($str, $max)
{
    if ( ! is_numeric($str))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return $str <= $max;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a callback to the controller, but I think that is not the optimal solution because `less_equals` is a very common rule.

- You should add the callback function to every controller
- You should write `callback_` a lot of times.

My solution for this problem (and other common rules like `is_date`), is extending the form validation library as follows:

Create `application/libraries/MY_form_validation.php`

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function less_equals($str, $min)
    {
        if ( ! is_numeric($str)) return FALSE;
        return $str <= $min;
    }

    //other rules here...
 }
```

Update `system/languaje/english/form_validation_lang.php` with the corresponding error message for `less_equals` and you are done! Now it works like any other Codeigniter default validation rule.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `less_than_equal_to[10]`.